# How to get all used values in columns in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with columns and values like this:

```
Column "A": 1, 5, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, ...
Column "B": 11, 15, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 10, 11, ...
Column "C": .... etc.
```

There is multiple columns in table with repeating numeric values.

I want to find out unique values in each column. So for column "A" it would return 1,2,3,4,5.

Currently I am using this query for one column:

`SELECT concat(A) FROM table GROUP BY A;`

But I don't know how to do it for multiple columns

Comment: Are this query : `SELECT concat(A) FROM table GROUP BY A;` works for you? since it's return `1, 5, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5` instead of `1,2,3,4,5`

Comment: Also, is Column A,B,C has a space between each values? Note that `1, 5, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5` are different from `1,5,3,2,3,1,4,5`. and `1` <> `<whitespace>1`.

Comment: I'm very confused about the specification. I suspect that OP has a table with rows `(a,b,c) VALUES (1,11,42),(5,15,25),(3,10,13),(2,12,14),(3,13,16),....` and that OP wants to return a single column `(val) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),...` This is a case where a SQL Fiddle would have expressed *much more clearly* the actual tables, columns, and exemplar values. As the question is currently written, with both example data and result as *comma separated list*, it's *unclear* what the author intended, as demonstrated by the comments and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a small enough set of values, you can use the `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate function, with the `DISTINCT` keyword

For example:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a ORDER BY a) AS a_values 
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b ORDER BY b) AS b_values 
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c ORDER BY c) AS c_values 
  FROM mytable
```

The length of the string returned by `GROUP_CONCAT` is limited by the `max_group_concat_len` variable (it's in the reference) and I think the `max_allowed_packet` also comes into play.

Compare the length of the string returned to `max_group_concat_len` to see if it's shorter, to know that the return string hasn't been silently truncated.

---

If you want to combine all of those values together, into a single distinct list, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT val ORDER BY val) AS col_values 
  FROM ( SELECT a AS val FROM mytable 
          UNION 
         SELECT b FROM mytable
          UNION
         SELECT c FROM mytable
       ) v
```

**EDIT**

I was confused by the use of the `CONCAT` function in the query, and misread the specification. The queries above return a **single** row, and returns a result that looks EXACTLY like what OP specified:

```
1,2,3,4,5,...
```

If we want to return each value on a separate row, a result that looks like this:

```
val
---
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
```

Then the query from Tim3880's answer does that, but the outer query isn't really necessary.

I'd want to add an ORDER BY, and actually write the query like this:

```
(SELECT a AS val FROM mytable)
UNION
(SELECT b AS val FROM mytable)
UNION
(SELECT c AS val FROM mytable)
ORDER BY 1
```

**EDIT**

Added SQL Fiddle showing how I interpret the specification (table, columns, exemplar values), and results from SQL statements above... one statement  returning distinct values as individual rows (query immediately above), and a statement returning a comma separated list (the first query in my answer.)

[**SQL Fiddle Example HERE** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d61c/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d61c/1)

If we want to identify which column(s) a value appears in

```
SELECT v.val
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT v.col ORDER BY v.col) AS in_cols
     , MAX(v.col='a') AS in_col_a
     , MAX(v.col='b') AS in_col_b
     , MAX(v.col='c') AS in_col_c
  FROM (
         SELECT a AS val, 'a' AS col FROM mytable
         UNION
         SELECT b AS val, 'b' AS col FROM mytable
         UNION
         SELECT c AS val, 'c' AS col FROM mytable
       ) v
 GROUP BY v.val
 ORDER BY v.val
```

Comment: And +1 for sqlfiddle, I didn't know about this one. Will use it in future questions for sure !

Answer (score 1):

If your query works for A, then you can do it for A, B, C using this:

```
SELECT A FROM 
( 
  SELECT A FROM table 
  UNION 
  SELECT B FROM table 
  UNION
  SELECT C FROM table
) e
```

as long as the three columns have compatible types.

Comment: There's no need for the `DISTINCT` keyword, and no need for an outer query. The `UNION` set operator is going to eliminate duplicate values. The inline view query (inside the parens) returns an equivalent result, without the outer query.

Comment: You are right. I used it to replace concat and it still useless.